# Create a list of dictionaries after you iterate over a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list :

```
programs = [PR1, PR2, PR3, PR4, PR5, PR6]
```

I iterate over it and get some information from db in a list :

```
for program in programs:
    db query = "....." % program
    number_of_users = [db query result]
    EX : number_of_users = [50, 100]
```

I want to know how to create a list of dictionaries like this :

```
 [{"PROGRAM_NAME" : program, "Number of users in 2020" : number_of_users[0], "Number of users in 2021" : number_of_users[1]},
  {"PROGRAM_NAME" : program, "Number of users in 2020" : number_of_users[0], "Number of users in 2021" : number_of_users[1]}, 
  {"PROGRAM_NAME" : program, "Number of users in 2020" : number_of_users[0], "Number of users in 2021" : number_of_users[1]},
.... and so on until the list is over]
```

Comment: This is not a [mre] - I get a NameError trying it. Please [edit] and fix. Also add what you did to get where you want to go to. You can create an empty list before the loop, you add your data to a new dictionary and add it to the list. Do until loop empty. What exactly is your problem with that? Do you know how to create a dict? Do you know how to create a list? Do you know how to add to either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to create an empty list, and fill it with dictionary values as follows:

```
newData = []
for program in programs:
    newDict = dict()
    db query = "....." % program
    number_of_users = [db query result]
    EX : number_of_users = [50, 100]
    newDict["PROGRAM_NAME"] = program
    newDict["Number of users in 2020"] = number_of_users[0]
    newDict["Number of users in 2021"] = number_of_users[1]
    newData.append(newDict.copy())
```

Don't forget to use the dictionary.copy, or else your dictionary will just be referenced in the list, and that will cause some issues

Edit: As mentioned by Łukasz Kwieciński, it is better as well if you do it in one line as:

```
newData = []
for program in programs:
    db query = "....." % program
    number_of_users = [db query result]
    EX : number_of_users = [50, 100]
    newDict = {"PROGRAM_NAME":program,"Number of users in 2020":number_of_users[0],"Number of users in 2021":number_of_users[1]}
    newData.append(newDict.copy())
```

Comment: why creating an empty dictionary and then adding all the key-value pairs when you can do it all in one line? `new_dict = {'PROGRAM_NAME': program, ...}`

Comment: I just thought it would be simpler to understand. But you are indeed correct.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to copy the dict. If _would_ if you added to it and added "different" states of the same dict - but you recreate a new one every loop.

Comment: Are you sure? I had some issues with similar situations when I didnt copy the dict, where when I re-assigned the dictionary it reassigned the already-assigned variables.